# React Native Mocking Platform.Version

Tags: react-native

I've been working with jest snapshots, and have some components which use the react-native.Platform. I need to have the Version and the OS set.

I am able to set `Platform.OS` manually just using `Platform.OS='android'` or `Platform.OS='ios'` but when I try and set `Platform.Version=21` it does not work. I looked a little deeper and found its using a getter for this. Is there anyway I'd be able to set `Platform.Version` similarly to how I am setting `Platform.OS`.

Answer (score 5):

The following trick works for me:

```
Object.defineProperty(Platform, 'Version', {
  get: () => 21
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great, can't believe this question seems so rare!